# Weight-based Object Matching in Java (not the actual weight on an object in memory)

Tags: java

I am trying to find a nice design to weight attributes in an object.

For example;

Object 'A' could have 4 fields all weight differently (for this example of fields will be weighted evenly). A new object of the same type is found and only some of its fields are the same. For this example 2 fields of object 'B' are equal to object 'A'. So it is 50% the same as object 'A'.

Another example in code;

```
Class Person{

    {Weight = 60}
    String name;

    {Weight = 20}
    String address;

    {Weight = 20}
    int age

    int weightBasedEqual(Person a, Person b)
    {
        //based on my weights I want to pass two Person objects and get a weighted value back
        //So in my example the names are the same but the two other fields are incorrect, 
        //but based on my weights it will return 60 as the match, where 100 was the top weight. 

        return value

   }

}
```

I want a way to say this object is some value the same, but where the weights of the attributes can change.

I hope that makes sense, so in short I would like a solution where each attribute of an object can be weighted and when an equals is done on the two objects a value is returned saying this object is that value the same.

Comment: No, what you're asking doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and annotation which will be available at runtime:

```
@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD})
@Inherited
@interface Weight{
    int value();
}
```

Then you can annotate class' fields

```
public class TestBean{

    @Weight(20)
    int field1;

    @Weight(80)
    int field2;
}
```

And than implement method which will do something will all fields with that annotation:

```
int weightBasedEqual(Person a, Person b)

        // For each field annotated with @Weight
        for(Field field : a.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){

            if(field.isAnnotationPresent(Weight.class)){

                // Get the weight
                int weight = field.getAnnotation(Weight.class).value();

                Object valueFromA = field.get(a); // Get field value for A 
                Object valueFromB = field.get(b); // Get field value for B
                // Compare the field value from 'a' and 'b' here and do with the weight whatever you like   
            }
       }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to calculate weightBasedEqual.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    static int nameWeight = 60;

    String address;
    static int addressWeight = 20;

    int age;
    static int ageWeight = 20;

    public int weightBasedEqual(Person a, Person b) {
        int value = 0;
        if (a.name.equalsIgnoreCase(b.name)) {
            value += nameWeight;
        }

        if (a.address.equalsIgnoreCase(b.address)) {
            value += addressWeight;
        }

        if (a.age == b.age) {  value += ageWeight; }
        return value;
    }

    public int weightBasedEqual(Person b) {
        return weightBasedEqual(this, b);
    }
}
```

The function works by adding the weight for each field if (and only if) the field exactly matches. As written, the function will return 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, or 100.

Note that there is one nameWeight, addressWeight, and ageWeight per Person class, by virtue of it being static.

I added a second weightBasedEqual, with a single person, because there will probably be times when you need to calculate the weight-based-equality on an existing object.